# Report Failed Error in Crystal Reports version 13.0?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, desktop-application

I have a project which has a crystal report which is been displayed on a winform. It runs perfectly on the project on Debug mood but once I create setup the crystal report area is totally not working and showing an error.

I'm using Crystal report 13 for Visual Studio 2013
After the error the system get close

Error Message

[image]

Comment: Whats in the Details of the Error. Expand "View problem details" and post the details please. Are you running the Program with the Setup on your development system or another fresh one with no crystal reports installation?

Comment: Running in my own system but the error is same at all machine

Comment: https://www.protectedtext.com/crystalerror check here the error if password require use solution

Comment: http://textuploader.com/52j5e

Comment: Thanks i expected to find more information in this text, sometimes it contains a stacktrace or at least an Exception type, which led to the crash. In this case i can only guess, like i did in my answer

Comment: Means I'm not getting your point

Answer (score 3):

For your Crystal Reports Viewer to work on a target machine, you need to deploy the CrystalReports runtime with your installation.
For an overview what you need for which Version of CR have a look at this site:
[Runtime Distributionand Supported Operating Systems](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports+v.+9.1+to+SAP+Crystal+Reports+2013,+Runtime+Distribution+and+Supported+Operating+Systems)

For the your version if you mean CR 2010 with "version 13.0" you need one of the runtimes from this site: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

**EDIT**

The ["Solution"](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/650794/Crystal-Reports-net-Application-Crashes-when-calli) from my last comment should just show you what you could try.

1. Install the right runtime (see links above)
2. If your app is compiled as 32Bit you need the 32Bit runtime even on a 64 bit system
3. Add the runtime policy shown in the solution to your app.config
4. If you use an obfuscator you shouldnt encrypt strings
5. upgrade your crystal reports Libs to the latest servicepack

Comment: I have the CRforVS_13_0_12 that included in Visual Studio 2013

Comment: I'm installing the runtime Crystal Report also in client machine CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_13 but still the same problem

Comment: Your app ist 64 or 32 bits? If you build it for x86 or 32bit system you neet the 32bit runtime.

Comment: That is okay man. Mu application is build for Any CPU but the thing it's not running in my machine also

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/650794/Crystal-Reports-net-Application-Crashes-when-calli